# ViewPager with ImageViews: Pages not swiping smoothly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a demo activity, which is essentially a collection of 5 images. I have these saved in my `/drawable` directory. I am using a custom implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter` because I have a static set of Fragments to page through:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        return SDemoFragment.newInstance(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

I have a custom implementation of `Fragment` as well. Currently, I have a single ImageView layout which I inflate, and depending on `mNum`, the image source is set to one of my image drawables.

```
public class SDemoFragment extends Fragment {
    int mNum = 0;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num" as an
     * argument.
     */
    public static SDemoFragment newInstance(int num) {
        SDemoFragment f = new SDemoFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null)
            mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
    }

    /**
     * The Fragment is created here.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item_fragment, container,
                false);
        ImageView x = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.pagerItemImage);

        switch (mNum) {
        case 0:
            x.setImageResource(R.drawable.demo0);
            break;
        case 1:
            x.setImageResource(R.drawable.demo1);
            break;
        case 2:
            x.setImageResource(R.drawable.demo2);
            break;
        case 3:
            x.setImageResource(R.drawable.demo3);
            break;
        case 4:
            x.setImageResource(R.drawable.demo4);
            break;
        }
        return x;

    }
}
```

Code for the simple image layout:
`pager_item_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pagerItemImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="Tutorial"
    android:src="@drawable/demo0" />
```

Is there any reason why every time I swipe from one image to the next, it lags? Is there an issue with memory, or using the right method, or calling `inflater.inflate(...);` every time `onCreateView()` is called? Any help would be appreciated, and if you need more sections of my code, don't hesitate to ask. Thanks!

Update: I'm now regularly getting an `OutOfMemoryException` too.

Comment: Have you read this ? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized my error thanks to @2Dee's link to the Android Developer Guide on Bitmap Loading: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

I moved the loading of all my Bitmaps to the parent Activity, and loaded them in an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ViewHolder pattern for minimizing the view lookups. Also offloading the image decoding to an AsyncTask would help a lot:

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Need to do this only once per each view.
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.mView = v.findViewById(R.id.pagerItemImage);
    holder.mPosition = position;

    new GetImageTask(position, holder).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
    return v;
}

private static class GetImageTask extends AsyncTask {

    private int mPosition;
    private ViewHolder mHolder;

    public GetImageTask(int pos, ViewHolder holder) {
        mPosition = pos;
        mHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // Update the appropriate slide
        if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
            // To be reconsidered. You can either set the returned image at runtime, and set it 
            // for your view, or you can store it inside the ViewHolder.
            mHolder.view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}


// This will hold all the data for you views.
private static class ViewHolder {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private int    mPosition; 
    private View   mView;
}
```

Please mind that this will store the bitmaps. Quite possibly you'll get an OutOfMemory at some points. 
More decent way to approach this would be required. For example, you should store only your current view, and its neighbours at some offset.

THis pseudo-code may be a bit not off-the-shelve but should be enough to display the general idea. For details on ViewHolders please see [Smooth Scrollin - Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html), as view pager/flipper will be almost the same case as listview.

Comment: Thanks! I think I just needed to start using `BitmapFactory.decode*()` and my problem was solved. I don't think I'll need to use `ViewHolders` just yet, but thank you!